# Connecting to SQL Server db through TADOConnection

Tags: sql-server, delphi

My database is on server that I connect to through a VPN tunnel. When I try to connect through SQL Server Management Studio, I do not have problem. When I try to connect with this Delphi component I get the message:

> Login failed for user . The user is not associated with a trusted SQL connection.

although in my connection string I have the user and password. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you seen [`this article`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555332) ?

Comment: "this" Delphi component? Which one?

Comment: @TLama that article is about server options, but Management Studio connects sucessfuly, so there is something with ADO connection options. @dzibul try to create `UDL` connection file and check connection with it. After that copy connection string into your app.

Comment: Are you using windows authentication?

Comment: @JanDoggen the component is TADOConnection (mentioned in the header)

Comment: @teran - if SQL is not setup for mixed mode then you will get this problem. (Studio uses windows authentication by default, if you specify username & password in the connection, standard authentication must be enabled on the server)

Comment: @whosrdaddy Sorry was only reading the question ;-)

Comment: You could try to connect a network drive on the remoteserver to have an authentication if you are using SQL Server Authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not quite enough in your question to answer with full confidence, but force your ADO connection string to utilize Windows Authentication:

> Network Library=DBMSSOCN; Integrated Security=SSPI; User Id=;
>   Password=; Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseName; Data
>   Source=YourServerName

**SSPI** is for Trusted Connections - uses the current security identity of the executing process. (The logged on user credentials)

**DBMSSOCN** is for TCPIP

Answer (score 1):

You should configure your MSSQL first, change security mode. It is "windows only" by default. Change it to "Windows and SQL server". This way you can connect with a user name and password. Otherwise you should be logged in to a domain server to generate SSPI context.